Could Java stream create memory overhead
What I got from basic principle of Java streams is that it works on immutable objects and does operation and collect (if we collect it as collection) as new immutable objects.
Does that means for any object there are two instances of an object

one before operation and
one after operation

If so does this mean for a application where memory is an issue, stream operations could create memory overhead?

"for any object there is two instance of object" no? If you do something like list.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()) (just "clone" a list via a stream) you won't get a clone of each object in the list. You'd get two lists in the end but it's hardly an overhead. And if you did something like list.stream().count() you won't get any extra objects.

Every operation producing a result that is not an already existing object requires memory to represent the result. That’s fundamental. The Stream API has operations which might result in an existing object and it has operations which will create a new object. There’s nothing special here.

If you want to create new objects or just a new list holding some of your old objects and you use a stream pipeline for it, the memory used for the new objects or new list can hardly be called overhead. The stream pipeline itself takes up memory which I would call overhead, but that’s small.


basic principle of java stream is that it works on immutable object

No, incorrect.
The elements of a stream can be mutable or immutable.

do operation and collect(if we collect it as collection) as new immutable object.

No, incorrect.
The collection produced by a stream (if any) can be modifiable or unmodifiable — your choice.

for any object there is two instance of object

Yes, if the stream produces a new object for each element of the stream. For example, Stream#map.
No, if the stream outputs the elements. For example, Stream#toList.
No, if the stream calculates statistics such as Stream#count.
